# Tagged Scrollbar like in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, api, styling

I need to implement a WPF Application which has to use the scrollbar like Visual Studio. That means it should tag regions of the scrollbar such as Warning, Error, Information etc.

Upon clicking on the tag it should scroll to the corresponding item on the pane/datagrid/whatever.

[image: Visual Studio Scrollbar]

What would be the proper way to perform this?
Is there and API/ Control Library out there to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since there were no reactions overall, I would like to post my own thoughts about this requirement. Maybe this will be of help to anybody.

The longer I thought about this I became clearer, that the Visual Studio Toolbar is simply a different representation of the source file which has been broken down to some details of interest. In the case of Visual Studio these are errors, code smells etc. 
In the easiest of all cases you simply can put a ListView above the Scrollbar or even the whole view and fix it to its width. Elements within this ListView can be small dashes in different colors with are registered to some kind of click event/command. When executed, it enables the scrollbar scrolls to the appropriate location.

Since we are using glorious Caliburn.Micro in our project, we will represent this view with a different context and provide some solution as above mentioned.

Comment: Do you have a solution for this? I'm wondering because I have to do exactly the same thing and would have to do it completely new. Thanks for your help.